# Is it considered bad practice to put a '.col-*-*' class directly on an element in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working in a codebase that is using Bootstrap 3. According to their documentation this is how you create a basic grid structure:

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
       <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    </div>
```

The code base I'm currently working in applies the grid structure in the following way.

```
     <div class="form-group">   
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4"> Name<span class="text-danger">*</span>  </label> 
        <div class="col-sm-8">
             <input type="text" class="col-xs-10" value="Default" name="panel:expandedContentContainer" id="id9428">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've never seen the grid applied in this way and I just want to make sure this won't cause problems down the road. I have two questions. Is it okay to use '.col-*-* without a row? And is it okay to put '.col-*-*' directly on elements?

Comment: I think it's a bad practice to use `.col--` directly on element, it may cause problem of styling. And you need to use the `.row` class in order to have the right padding on the left & right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3, the `.row` class will apply a negative margin of `($grid-gutter-width / 2)` to both the left and right.

The `.col-*` classes will apply a padding of `($grid-gutter-width / 2)` to both the left and right.

Adding the `.col-*` class to the sub elements will not necessarily cause you problems, but unless you override the padding on `.col-*` through your own CSS you will find elements will be indented more that you were perhaps hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use '.col--' without a row. Then it just isn't vertical align. more information about that: http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

And yes it is okay to put 'col--' directly on element. I don't have any bad experience with that.